EhCache 3 how to get the alias (name) of a Cache from a CacheEvent?
I have a generic listener for most of my caches and I do some logging when an event occurs.  The problem is that I don't know which cache is behind the event that I caught.  How do I get the cache's alias (i.e. name) ?
I have:

Spring Boot 3
EhCache 3.10.8
Caches are defined via xml

The configuration class (it reads in the .xml file ehcache.xml)
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

@Autowired
private javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager;

}

application.yml
spring:
  cache:
    jcache:
      config: classpath:ehcache.xml

ehcache.xml (in src/main/resources)
...
<cache alias="myCache">
    <listeners>
        <listener>
            <class>com.iznogoud.cache.DefaultListener</class>
            <event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>
            <event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>
            <events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on>
            <events-to-fire-on>EXPIRED</events-to-fire-on>
            <events-to-fire-on>EVICTED</events-to-fire-on>
            <events-to-fire-on>REMOVED</events-to-fire-on>
            <events-to-fire-on>UPDATED</events-to-fire-on>
        </listener>
    </listeners>
    <expiry>
        <ttl unit="seconds">10</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <heap unit="entries">10000</heap>
</cache>

My generic Listener class, com.iznogoud.cache.DefaultListener:
@Component
public class DefaultListener implements CacheEventListener<Object, Object> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER... 

    public DefaultListener() {}

    @Override
    public void onEvent(CacheEvent<?, ?> cacheEvent) {
        String cacheAlias = "dont-know!";
        String key = cacheEvent.getKey().toString();
        String = cacheEvent.getOldValue()==null?"null":cacheEvent.getOldValue().toString();
        String = cacheEvent.getNewValue()==null?"null":cacheEvent.getNewValue().toString();
        LOGGER.debug("Cache {}, EventType: {} : Key: {} |  | value {} -> {}",
                cacheAlias, cacheEvent.getType(), key, oldValue, newValue);
    }


Here's a somewhat-of-a-hack answer, but it works under I'm-testing-it-myself conditions:
In the @Configuration file where you define the cache manager add an init() method that constructs a map of the caches, and make the map public.
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager;  

    /** a mapping that enables Cache Listeners to get the name of the Cache when an event arrives **/
    public static HashMap<String, String> cacheNamesMap;

    /** ehCache Listeners don't know which cache they are dealing with.  (unless you have a listener class for each cache, ugh)
     But the cache manager here has all the aliases.
     So, make a map available between the instance of a cache (via .toString()) and it's name.
     The listeners use this map to find the alias of the cache that triggered the event.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        cacheNamesMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> cacheNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String nextName : cacheManager.getCacheNames()) {
            // use a key based on the underlying ehCache class, not the jCache class, the listeners are ehCache specific
            Cache nextCache = cacheManager.getCache(nextName).unwrap(org.ehcache.Cache.class);
            cacheNamesMap.put(nextCache.toString(), nextName);
        }
        LOGGER.debug("{} caches in cacheNamesMap.", cacheNamesMap.size());
        LOGGER.debug("  keys: {}", cacheNamesMap.keySet());
    }

Then access the map in your listener.
 @Override
 public void onEvent(CacheEvent<?, ?> cacheEvent) {
     Cache cache =  cacheEvent.getSource();
     String cacheAlias = CacheConfig.cacheNamesMap.get(cache.toString());  
     ...

Maybe it's not the most industrial waterproof solution but it works for me.  getSource() is, unfortunately, deprecated.
